# Relationship between slippery slope and reductio ad absurdum

Tags: argumentation

How should the [logical] relationship between the slippery slope [fallacy] and a reductio ad absurdum [argument] be characterized in order to succinctly capture their similarities and differences?  For instance, why is one a legitimate form of argumentation [if it is] and the other a fallacy [if it is]?

Comment: No relationship.

Comment: [Slippery slope is not a fallacy](https://www.foxven.com/pdf/slippery%20slope.pdf) if one plausibly establishes that there is a slope and it is indeed slippery, but the reasoning is based on chaining conditionals rather than a *reductio*. The former is an informal type of argument while the latter is formal. Beyond that it is hard to see what sort of parallel you have in mind to make a meaningful comparison.

Comment: @Conifold I often have discussions [arguments] with my 26 yo engineer nephew and deploy the reductio [in typical fashion] as a  a method of refuting a claim by extending the logic of the opponent's argument (x implies y implies z...) to a point of absurdity.   That "extension" can be interpreted as either a reductio or a slippery slope (which has been my nephews reaction to my argument].  Could be that both are legitimate forms of argument or fallacies, depending upon the how they are used.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA. Really? Wiki: A reductio is often deployed in a manner that results in a logicl  fallacy, in a similar manner to the slippery slope. The fallacious nature of this use of the arg lies in the assumption that in order for something to be true, it must be true in all circumstances. eg, the assertion that if a reduction in working hours results in an increase in productivity then working no hours would result in the highest productivity. The fallacious nature of this argument lies in assuming that the relationship between working hours and productivity is entirely linear.

Comment: What you describe isn't ["slippery slope"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slippery_slope) as normally used. It isn't supposed to lead to a contradiction in reasoning as such, but rather to a consequence undesirable due to what it is about. The slippery chain is causal, not logical. Even if we extend the metaphor, it would just be a combination of "slippery slope" with *reductio*, not something interpretable one way or the other alone.

Comment: @Conifold: "Even if we extend the metaphor, it would just be a combination of "slippery slope" with reductio, not something interpretable one way or the other alone."  Discuss.

Comment: If I use proof by cases to get a *reductio* in each case I am not using either proof by cases or *reductio* alone, but both. Nothing changes when replacing proof by cases with "slippery slope".

Comment: @Conifold  BTW I am fully aware that the a contradiction is not the necessary result.  But, as is more often that not the case, simply an untoward/undesired/pernicious/nefarious, etc. result.  Maybe that's the difference, when properly deplyed a reductio always leads to absurdity, contradiction, which is not the case with the slippery slope.  Thank you.  You led me to answer the query myself

Comment: So its a matter of the rhetorical tactic of whom is doing the characterizing.   The one making the [reductio + proof by cases] argument or his interlocutor/opponent.

Comment: *Logical fallacies* are incorrect use of logical rules, producing invalid inferences, like e.g.  Affirming the consequent. There are a more general category of fallacies, that we may call "Fallacies of argumentation", like e.g. Ad hominem that are not invalid logical arguments but are "rethorical devices" used to obtain consent in a (sometimes) incorrect way. Reductio is a valid argument: thus, no fallacy whatever.

Comment: The slippery slope is a fallacy because there are possibilities that one can have all true premises while the conclusion is FALSE. The reductio ad absurdum is an indirect proof that the conclusion is impossible to be false. That is even when we assume the argument premises false I get a BLATANTLY asurd answer. That alone shows that the line of reasoning being used is unreliable.  Unreliable reasoning allows true premises & a false conclusion. So there is no relation between the two legitimately.  One is good reasoning while the other is always unreliable. Intention or rhetoric is not a factor.